# es_exporter service configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus

While setting up ElasticSearch Exporter's service, I came up with this below content

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus ES_exporter
After=local-fs.target network-online.target network.target
Wants=local-fs.target network-online.target network.target

[Service]
User=root
Nice=10
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/es_exporter --es.uri=http://elastic_user:XXXXXXXXXXX@localhost:9200 --es.all --es.indices --es.timeout 20s
ExecStop= /usr/bin/killall es_exporter

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I din't get what values to be put in....

```
 http://elastic_user:XXXXXXXXXXX@localhost:9200
```

Will it be like .... ?

`http://elastic_user(by which I am starting peocess):(PASSWORD)@(IP/LOCALHOST):9200`

[ *Additional Info :  These changes are being used to Monitor ElasticSearch Cluster using Prometheus and Grafana* ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation, this is written :

*the address of a remote Elasticsearch server. When basic auth is needed, specify as: ://:@:. E.G., http://admin:pass@localhost:9200.*

The documentation here : https://github.com/prometheus-community/elasticsearch_exporter#configuration

An example here :
https://github.com/Lyr/ansible-elasticsearch-exporter/blob/master/templates/elasticsearch_exporter.service.j2